# One Twilio iOS SDK for both voip and cell calls?

Tags: twilio

We would like to be able to make both voip and regular cell calls from our native iOS app, using Twilio. For voip, we'd like to use WebRTC, because it's cheaper and probably more reliable. Does anyone know if there's a single Twilio SDK to accomplish this? That is, is it possible to call a cell phone using the Programmable Voice SDK, or any other Twilio SDK besides Client SDK? Or is the Twilio REST api the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are set with the VOIP solution - using the [iOS Client SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios).

As for Programmable Voice - you would need to facilitate this via [the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls).

Where an example app using a Python back-end for example would look like:

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    to="+1XXXXXXXXXX",
    from_="+1XXXXXXXXXX")
print(call.sid)
```